# Is it possible to import a table with sqoop and add an extra timestamp column?

Tags: oracle, hadoop, timestamp, sqoop

is it possible to use the sqoop command "import table" to import a table from an oracle database to an Hadoop cluster and add an extra column with the current timestamp (for troubleshouting purposes)? so far, I have the following command:

`sqoop import -Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//MY_ORACLE_SERVER --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --target-dir /MyDIR --fields-terminated-by '\b' --table SOURCE_TABLE  --hive-table DESTINATION_TABLE  --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-delims-replacement '<newline>'`

I would like to add a timestamp column to the table so that I know when that data was loaded. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you make a view in Oracle containing the time? Or you want the time it actually landed in HDFS?

Comment: I don't have permissions over the Oracle DB. I would like to know the time data landed on HDFS

Answer (score 1):

you can use the free-form query import instead of table import, and call the timestamp function :

```
sqoop import -Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//MY_ORACLE_SERVER --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --target-dir /MyDIR --fields-terminated-by '\b' ----query 'SELECT a.*,systimestamp FROM SOURCE_TABLE a' --hive-table DESTINATION_TABLE  --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-delims-replacement '<newline>'
```

Maybe you could use sysdate instead systimestamp (smaller datatype but less precision)

Comment: This should work, although, I need to specify the --split-by option and $CONDITIONS in the where clause. Based on this I used the following:

sqoop import -Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//MY_ORACLE_SERVER --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --target-dir /MyDIR --fields-terminated-by '\b' --query 'SELECT a.*,sysdate as load_date FROM SOURCE_TABLE a where $CONDITIONS' --hive-table DESTINATION_TABLE --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-delims-replacement '<newline>' --split-by SOURCE_TABLE_ID

Works but the is not uploaded

Comment: Its almost as the table has that predefined source columns and if I want to add another one I need to create a new table, based on anther one

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temp hive table by using sqoop ,after that create a new hive table by using old one with extra required columns.

Comment: I think this might me the option because when I import the table I am not able to change its structure. I would have to create a new hive table with the additional options based on the imported table. Does that make sense for you?

Comment: I think, sqoop is dedicated  only for the data present in tables , we can't add columns  for the existing tables while importing. So just go with the same approach

Comment: Right, so, that means that every column I want to add has to be added within HDFS. No Sqoop involved. Am I right?

Comment: Yes , this is the best approach.